# rails2 custom callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I'm using rails 2.3.10 and I'm trying to do the following

I have many models in which I have methods to do certain tasks that do not save or update a model, and I want to keep track of who and when these tasks were performed

I'd like to be able to do something like this in certain model:

```
# myModel.rb
track :send_email, :send_fax, :accept_invite

def send_email
  ...
end

def send_fax
  ...
end

def accept_invite
  ...
end
```

and after each of these, perform another set of tasks, such as saving this info to the db

How could I set callbacks such as after_send_email, after_send_fax, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3
But I don't think it's the best way to go. Still interesting though.

edit: sorry, forget about that, I was thinking about controller callbacks...

Maybe you can just do something like:

```
after_filter :after_send_email, :only => [:send_email]

def after_send_email
end
```